# ES6: Loop through objects and assign one of it value to Select fields value and text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to loop through the below data structure and set 'Select' fields options. This is where I have an issue. I'm trying to assign 'nameCombined' & 'codeCombined' to the value and text of the Select Form field.

DataStructure:

```json
{
   "Bucks":{
      "countyCode":"42017",
      "globalStateCode":"PA",
      "stateCode":"PA",
      "nameCombined":"42017 (PA)",
      "codeCombined":"42017 PA Bucks"
   },
   "Montgomery":{
      "countyCode":"42091",
      "globalStateCode":"PA",
      "stateCode":"PA",
      "nameCombined":"42091 (PA)",
      "codeCombined":"42091 PA Montgomery"
   }
}
```

## React JSX

## Select Component

```
const {
  name,
  options,
  actions: { handleFieldChange },
} = props;

<select id={name} onChange={(e) => handleValueChange(e)}>
  {options.map((option, idx) => (
    <option key={`${option.value}_${idx}`} value={option.value}>
      {value === option.text}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>;

    
// The component that consumes Select Component
// ============================================
    
<Select
   inputData={{
       name:name,
        options:Object.entries(counties).map(([key, item]) => ({'value': item.nameCombined, 'text': item.codeCombined})), // <- this line needs attention
        type:INPUT_TYPES.DROPDOWN,
   }},
   actions={{
      handleFieldChange: handleDropdownChange
   }}
/>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Is there an error? Unexpected behavior? I don't see anything overtly incorrect about the way you've mapped the entry values to select option values. It doesn't appear as though you touch the entry key, so `Object.values` may be a slightly better fit. The `value === option.text` rendered option display value is a little odd though. What is `value` here? Can you provide a more complete code example?

Comment: @Drew Reese -- it showed me an error. Error was that it was complaining about having ':' in the return

Comment: I still don't see anything syntactically wrong with the line you point to. If you've an error then you should include that as relevant information in your question.

Comment: FYI, here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-mayer-dro9k?file=/src/App.js) of ***your*** code running without issue. It's still not clear what your issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead of `Object.entries`.

```
Object.keys(counties).map(key => ({value: counties[key].nameCombined, item: counties[key].codeCombined}))
```

The conceptual limitation that you have in your assumption is that you need a proper array to iterate and `Object.entries` gives you `[[key1, object1],...]` while `Object.keys` gives you `[key1, key2]`.